# Unable to Access PostgreSQL Tables via SQLAlchemy in Google Colab, but Works Fine via gcloud Command Line

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-sql

Question:
I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Google Cloud SQL from a Google Colab notebook. I am using SQLAlchemy with the pg8000 driver. The issue is that I am unable to access the tables in the database, even though the same tables are accessible when I connect via the gcloud command line tool.

What I've tried:
Case Sensitivity: Ensured that the table names are exactly as they were created.
Schema: Checked that the schema is the same in both the working and non-working cases.
Connection String: Verified that the database name, user, password, host, and port are correct.
Code:
Here's the Python code I am using to connect:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

def connect_with_connector():
    db_user = 'postgres'
    db_pass = '*****'  # Hidden for security
    db_name = 'johannes-castner-info'
    db_host = 'xx.xx.xx.xxx'
    db_port = '5432'

    engine = create_engine(
        f'postgresql+pg8000://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'
    )
    return engine

def main():
    engine = connect_with_connector()
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        stmt = text('SELECT * FROM Education')
        result = connection.execute(stmt)
        print(result.fetchall())

main()
```

Error:
When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError) {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42P01', 'M': 'relation "education" does not exist', 'P': '15', 'F': 'parse_relation.c', 'L': '1395', 'R': 'parserOpenTable'}
```

Working gcloud command:
When I connect via the gcloud command line tool, everything works fine:

```
>gcloud sql connect johannes-castner-info --user=postgres --project chatbot-xxxxxx
...
postgres=> \dt
List of relations
Schema | Name | Type | Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
public | education | table | postgres
...
(9 rows)
```

`
Question:
Why am I unable to access the tables via SQLAlchemy in Google Colab, even though I can access them via the gcloud command line tool?  It looks as if I'm in the same database; same search path, same data directory, same user, yet in one of those versions I can list the tables and they are there and in the other there are no tables.  Puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says:

```
'relation "education" does not exist'
```

That means you're trying to read from a database table that doesn't exist. The connection is otherwise succeeding.

Comment: yes but then the question is why does this exact same table exist when I log into that same database as the same user via gcloud sql command line; that is what is so puzzling; it has the same search path with public in it and there are these tables when I do \dt including the "education" table ...but the same exact tables are all missing when I connect via alchemy with the pg8000 driver.

Comment: Double check that you're connecting to the same instance in both cases. I see nothing wrong with your connection string otherwise.

Comment: it's been driving me crazy yesterday but I haven't had a chance yet to get back to it; I burned a good morning on it already and I can't find anything different about how I do things ; yet it seems as though I'm in entirely different databases!

Comment: Have you tried running `SELECT * FROM education` when connecting from gcloud?

Comment: yes; all of the tables are gone!  I tried `\dt` in both logins. Using alchemy, with the pg8000 driver, I see no tables; all are gone, while with `gcloud sql connect johannes-castner-info --user=postgres --project chatbot-397713`  either from my own laptop or from the Google Cloud shell or any other environment; I then do ```postgres=> \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | education       | table | postgres
... public | work_experience | table | postgres
(9 rows)
```